# Make error with Grib2 and Netcdf

Tags: makefile

I am trying to install a software package designed for weather modeling. This can be found here https://github.com/usgs/volcano-ash3d-metreader. The issue comes when I am trying to execute the 'Make all' command. When running I get the output of:

```
    /usr/bin/gfortran -O0 -g3 -Wall -fbounds-check -pedantic -fimplicit-none -Wunderflow -Wuninitialized -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow -fdefault-real-8   -L./ -lMetReader -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/opt/USGS/lib -I/usr/lib -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/opt/USGS/include -I/usr/local/lib   -lnetcdff -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -lnetcdf -lnetcdf -leccodes -leccodes_f90 -c tools/MetSonde.f90
    /usr/bin/gfortran -O0 -g3 -Wall -fbounds-check -pedantic -fimplicit-none -Wunderflow -Wuninitialized -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow -fdefault-real-8   MetSonde.o  -L./ -lMetReader -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/opt/USGS/lib -I/usr/lib -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/opt/USGS/include -I/usr/local/lib   -lnetcdff -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -lnetcdf -lnetcdf -leccodes -leccodes_f90 -L/opt/USGS/lib -I/opt/USGS/include -lhourssince -lprojection -o tools/MetSonde
    /usr/bin/gfortran -x f95-cpp-input -DFORWARD  -O0 -g3 -Wall -fbounds-check -pedantic -fimplicit-none -Wunderflow -Wuninitialized -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow -fdefault-real-8   tools/MetTraj.F90 -o tools/MetTraj_F -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/opt/USGS/lib -I/usr/lib -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/opt/USGS/include -I/usr/local/lib   -lnetcdff -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -lnetcdf -lnetcdf -leccodes -leccodes_f90 -L./ -lMetReader -L/opt/USGS/lib -I/opt/USGS/include -lhourssince -lprojection
    .//libMetReader.a(MetReader_NetCDF.o): In function `mr_set_met_dims_template_netcdf_':
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:2249: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_open'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:2251: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:2279: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_inq_dimid'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:2281: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:2282: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:2285: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_inquire_dimension'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:2287: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:2288: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:2298: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_inq_varid'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:2300: undefined 
.
.
.
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:2871: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:2872: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:2885: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_get_var_4d_fourbytereal'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:2887: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:2888: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:2902: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_get_var_3d_fourbytereal'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:2904: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:2905: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:3061: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_close'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:3063: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_NetCDF.f90:3064: undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror'
    .//libMetReader.a(MetReader_GRIB.o): In function `mr_read_met_dimvars_grib_':
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:104: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_open_file'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:105: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_new_from_file'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:107: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_int'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:108: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_release'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:109: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_close_file'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:123: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_open_file'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:125: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_new_from_file'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:134: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_int'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:135: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_int'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:141: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_string'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:142: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_real8'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:144: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_real8'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:149: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_int'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:186: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_int'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:190: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_data_real8'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:202: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_real8'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:208: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_real8'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:214: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_real8'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:216: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_real8'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:225: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_int'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:229: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_data_real8'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:241: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_real8'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:247: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_real8'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:259: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_real8'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:279: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_real8'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:281: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_real8'
    .//libMetReader.a(MetReader_GRIB.o):/home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:283: more undefined references to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_real8' follow
    .//libMetReader.a(MetReader_GRIB.o): In function `mr_read_met_dimvars_grib_':
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:306: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_int'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:308: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_int'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:311: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_int' 

.
.
.
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:1378: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_index_release'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:1385: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_open_file'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:1388: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_multi_support_on'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:1391: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_new_from_file'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:1395: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_int'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:1396: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_int'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:1397: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_int'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:1398: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_int'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:1399: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_int'
    .//libMetReader.a(MetReader_GRIB.o):/home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:1400: more undefined references to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_int' follow
    .//libMetReader.a(MetReader_GRIB.o): In function `mr_read_metp_variable_grib_':
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:1423: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_get_real8_array'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:1443: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_release'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:1444: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_new_from_file'
    /home/trevor/Downloads/volcano-ash3d-metreader-master/MetReader_GRIB.f90:1446: undefined reference to `__grib_api_MOD_grib_close_file'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    makefile:174: recipe for target 'MetTraj_F' failed
    make: *** [MetTraj_F] Error 1
```

I believe my makefile is simply not refrencing the correct locations for grib_api_mod and NetCDF_Mod but I cant seem to figure out the best way to correct this. Here I have also attached the make file I am executing.

```
##############################################################################
#  Makefile for libmetreader.a
#
#    User-specified flags are in this top block
#
###############################################################################

#      This file is a component of the volcanic ash transport and dispersion model Ash3d,
#      written at the U.S. Geological Survey by Hans F. Schwaiger (hschwaiger@usgs.gov),
#      Larry G. Mastin (lgmastin@usgs.gov), and Roger P. Denlinger (roger@usgs.gov).

#      The model and its source code are products of the U.S. Federal Government and therefore
#      bear no copyright.  They may be copied, redistributed and freely incorporated 
#      into derivative products.  However as a matter of scientific courtesy we ask that
#      you credit the authors and cite published documentation of this model (below) when
#      publishing or distributing derivative products.

#      Schwaiger, H.F., Denlinger, R.P., and Mastin, L.G., 2012, Ash3d, a finite-
#         volume, conservative numerical model for ash transport and tephra deposition,
#         Journal of Geophysical Research, 117, B04204, doi:10.1029/2011JB008968. 

#      We make no guarantees, expressed or implied, as to the usefulness of the software
#      and its documentation for any purpose.  We assume no responsibility to provide
#      technical support to users of this software.

#  SYSTEM specifies which compiler to use
#    Current available options are:
#      gfortran , ifort
#    This variable cannot be left blank
#      
SYSTEM = gfortran
#
#  RUN specifies which collection of compilation flags that should be run
#    Current available options are:
#      DEBUG : includes debugging info and issues warnings
#      PROF  : includes profiling flags with some optimization
#      OPT   : includes optimizations flags for fastest runtime
#    This variable cannot be left blank
RUN =DEBUG
#
INSTALLDIR=/opt/USGS
#INSTALLDIR=~/gcc
#
# DATA FORMATS
#  For each data format you want to include in the library, set the corresponding
#  variable below to 'T'.  Set to 'F' any you do not want compiled or any unavailable
USENETCDF = T
USEGRIB = T

# MEMORY
# If you need pointer arrays instead of allocatable arrays, set this to 'T'
USEPOINTERS = F

###############################################################################
#####  END OF USER SPECIFIED FLAGS  ###########################################
###############################################################################

FPPFLAGS = 
ifeq ($(USENETCDF), T)
 ncFPPFLAG = -DUSENETCDF
 ncOBJS = MetReader_NetCDF.o
 nclib = -lnetcdff -lnetcdf
else
 ncFPPFLAG =
 ncOBJS =
 nclib =
endif
ifeq ($(USEGRIB), T)
 grbFPPFLAG = -DUSEGRIB
 grbOBJS = MetReader_GRIB.o MetReader_GRIB_index.o
 # These are the libraries for grib_api
 #grblib = -lgrib_api_f90 -lgrib_api
 # These are the libraries for ecCodes
 grblib = -leccodes -leccodes_f90
else
 grb2FPPFLAG =
 grb2OBJS =
 grblib =
endif

ifeq ($(USEPOINTERS), T)
 memFPPFLAG = -DUSEPOINTERS
else
 memFPPFLAG =
endif

FPPFLAGS = -x f95-cpp-input $(ncFPPFLAG) $(grbFPPFLAG) $(grbFPPFLAG) $(memFPPFLAG)

# location of HoursSince and projection
USGSLIBDIR = -L$(INSTALLDIR)/lib
USGSINC = -I$(INSTALLDIR)/include
USGSLIB = $(USGSLIBDIR) $(USGSINC) -lhourssince -lprojection

EXEC = \
 gen_GRIB_index   \
 tools/MetSonde  \
 tools/MetTraj_F \
 tools/MetTraj_B \
 tools/MetCheck  \
 tools/makegfsncml

###############################################################################
###############################################################################

###############################################################################
##########  GNU Fortran Compiler  #############################################
ifeq ($(SYSTEM), gfortran)
    FCHOME=/usr
    FC = /usr/bin/gfortran

    COMPINC = -I$(FCHOME)/local/include -I$(FCHOME)/include -I$(FCHOME)/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -I$(INSTALLDIR)/include -I$(FCHOME)/local/lib 
    COMPLIBS = -L$(FCHOME)/local/lib -L$(FCHOME)/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L${INSTALLDIR}/lib -I$(FCHOME)/lib

    #COMPINC = -I$(FCHOME)/include  -I$(INSTALLDIR)/include
    #COMPLIBS = -L$(FCHOME)/lib64 -L${INSTALLDIR}/lib

    LIBS = $(COMPLIBS) $(COMPINC) #-lefence
    # -lefence 
# Debugging flags
ifeq ($(RUN), DEBUG)
    FFLAGS =  -O0 -g3 -Wall -fbounds-check -pedantic -fimplicit-none -Wunderflow -Wuninitialized -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow -fdefault-real-8 
endif
# Profiling flags
ifeq ($(RUN), PROF)
    FFLAGS = -g -pg -w -fno-math-errno -funsafe-math-optimizations -fno-trapping-math -fno-signaling-nans -fcx-limited-range -fno-rounding-math -fdefault-real-8
endif
# Production run flags
ifeq ($(RUN), OPT)
    FFLAGS = -O3 -w -fno-math-errno -funsafe-math-optimizations -fno-trapping-math -fno-signaling-nans -fcx-limited-range -fno-rounding-math -fdefault-real-8
endif
    EXFLAGS =
endif
###############################################################################

all: libMetReader.a tools

libMetReader.a: MetReader.F90 MetReader.o $(ncOBJS) $(grbOBJS) MetReader_Grids.o MetReader_ASCII.o makefile
    ar rcs libMetReader.a MetReader.o $(ncOBJS) $(grbOBJS) MetReader_Grids.o MetReader_ASCII.o

MetReader.o: MetReader.F90 makefile
    $(FC) $(FPPFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) -c MetReader.F90
MetReader_Grids.o: MetReader_Grids.f90 MetReader.o makefile
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) $(LIBS) -c MetReader_Grids.f90
MetReader_ASCII.o: MetReader_ASCII.f90 MetReader.o makefile
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) $(LIBS) -c MetReader_ASCII.f90

ifeq ($(USENETCDF), T)
MetReader_NetCDF.o: MetReader_NetCDF.f90 MetReader.o makefile
    $(FC) $(FPPFLAGS) $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(nclib) $(USGSLIB) -c MetReader_NetCDF.f90
endif
ifeq ($(USEGRIB), T)
MetReader_GRIB_index.o: MetReader_GRIB_index.f90 makefile
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(grblib) $(USGSLIB) -c MetReader_GRIB_index.f90
MetReader_GRIB.o: MetReader_GRIB.f90 MetReader_GRIB_index.o MetReader.o makefile
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(grblib) -c MetReader_GRIB.f90
gen_GRIB_index: gen_GRIB_index.f90 MetReader_GRIB_index.o makefile libMetReader.a
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(grblib) -c gen_GRIB_index.f90
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) MetReader_GRIB_index.o gen_GRIB_index.o $(LIBS) $(grblib) -o gen_GRIB_index
endif


ifeq ($(USEGRIB), T)
  GRIBTOOL = gen_GRIB_index
else
  GRIBTOOL =
endif

tools: MetSonde MetTraj_F MetTraj_B MetCheck makegfsncml $(GRIBTOOL)

MetSonde: tools/MetSonde.f90 makefile libMetReader.a
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) -L./ -lMetReader $(LIBS) $(nclib) $(grblib) -c tools/MetSonde.f90
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) MetSonde.o  -L./ -lMetReader $(LIBS) $(nclib) $(grblib) $(USGSLIB) -o tools/MetSonde
MetTraj_F: tools/MetTraj.F90 makefile libMetReader.a
    $(FC) -x f95-cpp-input -DFORWARD  $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) tools/MetTraj.F90 -o tools/MetTraj_F $(LIBS) $(nclib) $(grblib) -L./ -lMetReader $(USGSLIB)
MetTraj_B: tools/MetTraj.F90 makefile libMetReader.a
    $(FC) -x f95-cpp-input -DBACKWARD $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) tools/MetTraj.F90 -o tools/MetTraj_B $(LIBS) $(nclib) $(grblib) -L./ -lMetReader $(USGSLIB)
MetCheck: tools/MetCheck.f90 makefile libMetReader.a
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(nclib) $(grblib) -c tools/MetCheck.f90
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) MetCheck.o $(LIBS) $(nclib) $(grblib) -L./ -lMetReader $(USGSLIB) -o tools/MetCheck
makegfsncml: tools/makegfsncml.f90 makefile
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(nclib) -c tools/makegfsncml.f90
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) makegfsncml.o  $(LIBS) $(nclib) -o tools/makegfsncml

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.mod
    rm -f lib*.a
    rm -f $(EXEC)

install:
    install -d $(INSTALLDIR)/lib/
    install -d $(INSTALLDIR)/include/
    install -d $(INSTALLDIR)/bin/
    install -d $(INSTALLDIR)/bin/autorun_scripts
    install -m 644 libMetReader.a $(INSTALLDIR)/lib/
    install -m 644 *.mod $(INSTALLDIR)/include/
    install -m 755 $(EXEC) $(INSTALLDIR)/bin/
    install -m 755 autorun_scripts/*.sh $(INSTALLDIR)/bin/autorun_scripts/
```

Any help or suggestions with this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you also use the AVO-G2S model? Maybe we can talk about this. I also meet some problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an issue of library linkage order - in particular, since `libMetReader` depends on both NetCDF and Grib, they must follow it (rather than preceding it) in the link command:

```
$ diff makefile.orig makefile
174c174
<   $(FC) -x f95-cpp-input -DFORWARD  $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) tools/MetTraj.F90 -o tools/MetTraj_F $(LIBS) $(nclib) $(grblib) -L./ -lMetReader $(USGSLIB)
---
>   $(FC) -x f95-cpp-input -DFORWARD  $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) tools/MetTraj.F90 -o tools/MetTraj_F $(LIBS) -L./ -lMetReader $(nclib) $(grblib) $(USGSLIB)
176c176
<   $(FC) -x f95-cpp-input -DBACKWARD $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) tools/MetTraj.F90 -o tools/MetTraj_B $(LIBS) $(nclib) $(grblib) -L./ -lMetReader $(USGSLIB)
---
>   $(FC) -x f95-cpp-input -DBACKWARD $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) tools/MetTraj.F90 -o tools/MetTraj_B $(LIBS) -L./ -lMetReader $(nclib) $(grblib) $(USGSLIB)
179c179
<   $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) MetCheck.o $(LIBS) $(nclib) $(grblib) -L./ -lMetReader $(USGSLIB) -o tools/MetCheck
---
>   $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(EXFLAGS) MetCheck.o $(LIBS) -L./ -lMetReader $(nclib) $(grblib) $(USGSLIB) -o tools/MetCheck
```

For a more detailed explanation see [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Comment: I did not know that, thank you for bringing that to my attention. This seems to have fixed the issue I was running in to! Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: @LvnTrvr glad to help - some futher explanation here: [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)